# How to plot time series graph with categories?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, time-series

I've data in Google Spreadsheets, with columns as follows:

```
DD.MM.YYYY CATEGORY COUNTER_1 COUNTER_2
```

For example:

```
22.12.2010 APPLES    1 20
23.12.2010 APPLES  100 20
23.12.2010 ORANGES  32 12
```

I need to plot this data on a graph, with separate lines for each category and counter. I can't figure out how to do this.

Any clues?

Comment: I gave a shot at it as well but without success. You have simply said, to many variables.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem in the meantime?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 3):

Alexander, as stated in my comment on the 27th of November 2012, I see no possibility to add all the series into one chart, like the way *you* present them. I did however found a way to do it, but this approach is heavily compromised:
[image]
The trick is to create fruit dependent counters. See example file I've created: **[Fruit Counters](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdE10NHB3Sjh1SnZzb2pIeXhNYVdrNWc&usp=sharing)**
I hope I'm wrong and that somebody else finds the solution.

Comment: Maybe some scripting?

Comment: I will take a deeper look into it, OK?

Comment: Did you look into it?

Comment: I've prepared a script, but wasn't able to make it happen, right-a-way. I will continue @AlexanderGladysh with it along the way....

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh I've added a pivot table and graph to te example file. In the pivot table you will be able to select te different dates. The CHART_3 will show the respective summations.

I will stop to try and make it work in a GAS, because it simply isn't possible. Good luck with the solutions.